# How to add query param before navigation start in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router, query-string

Let's say I have two components `A` and `B`. Component A navigates to `/a?random=random` and B navigates to `/b`. I want to add `authUser` query param before navigation starts so end result should look like this `/a?random=random&authUser=1`, `/b?authUser=1` respectively.
The problem is that url for component `A` looks like this `/a?authUser=1` after appending the `authUser` queryParam not `/a?random=random&authUser=1`.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpamcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link.

```
// App component
 ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
         if (!event.url.includes('authUser')) {
          // remove queryParams
          const url = event.url.split('?')[0];
          if (url !== '/') {
            // /a/etc => ['a','etc']
            const newUrl = url.split('/').filter(_subUrl => _subUrl);
            this.router.navigate(newUrl, { queryParams: { authUser: '1' }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }

  navigateToA() {
    this.router.navigate(['a'], { queryParams: { random: 'random' } });
  }

  navigateToB() {
    this.router.navigate(['b']);
  }
```

I don't wanna make changes to component `A` and `B` navigate methods because in real applications then i'll have to make changes to every navigate method which would be a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

exampe fo query param`this.router.navigate([`/${this.appStatus.baseUrl}/predict/result`], {queryParams: {vsgid: vsgid, sid: sid, logo: logo}});`

Comment: Sorry, Didn't get it.